# How to properly use (assert) in this case with Python?

Tags: python, set, assert

I am a very new user to Python. I am writing a simple code to return two things: the union of two sets (where each of them contains numbers and words) as well as the length of the union set.
I am trying to use `assert` with a very simple example as shown below, however, it keeps giving me `AssertionError`.
This is how I defined the function:

```
def union(A, B):
    AuB = A.union(B)
    total = (AuB,len(AuB))
    print(total)
```

then I use this to execute it:

```
A = {1,4,-3, "bob"}
B = {2,1,-3,"jill"}
union(A,B)
assert union(A,B) == ({-3, 1, 2, 4, 'bob', 'jill'}, 6)
```

However, this is the resulting error:

```
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-cb63795cc161> in <module>()
      2 B = {2,1,-3,"jill"}
      3 union(A,B)
----> 4 assert union(A,B) == ({-3, 1, 2, 4, 'bob', 'jill'}, 6)

AssertionError:
```

Please advise what is the best way to use `assert` in this case, as I have to use it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `def union` instead of `print` use return.

```
def union(A, B):
  AuB = A.union(B)
  total = (AuB,len(AuB))
  return total
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is not in how to use `assert` but what you are trying to assert. Your `union` function prints a "result" but actually returns `None` (because you don't have any `return` statement). So you are actually asserting `None == ({-3, 1, 2, 4, 'bob', 'jill'}, 6)` which is `False`, use `return total` instead of (or in addition to if you really want to) `print(total)`.